# Eclipse XSL option missing in preferences

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt, eclipse-mars

I am a newbie to Java, I am using Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1). For XSLT transformations I need to use the saxon processor. But, when I navigate to Window -> Preferences -> XML I don't see the options for XSL. This is strange because my other colleagues see this option in their (same version of) Eclipse.

How can I get the XSL options?

Thanks  :)

[I am attaching an image of "how it should be" and "how it is".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXqhV.png)

Comment: Don't confuse the *version* with the *package* itself. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=mars

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several different downloads of each release of Eclipse. The contents of these downloads varies. It looks like you may have a download which does not contain the XSL tools.

You can add the tools to your existing Eclipse by opening 'Help > Install New Software...'.

In 'Work with' choose 'Mars - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars'.

Search for 'XSL' and you should find 'Eclipse XSL Developer Tools'.